# Using buffered image to render a sprite

Tags: java, eclipse, image, canvas, boolean

I'm trying to use a buffered image to render a sprite from a sprite sheet but I can't figure out why my code isn't working even though I'm calling up the image from the class?

Code:

```
package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;
    boolean sprite = false;
    private BufferedImage sprite;

    public void init(){
        BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
        try{

            spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/astronaut_sprite1.png");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

    private void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;

        }

        if(sprite == true){
            g.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            System.out.println("True");
        }

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_1){
            sprite = true;
        }

}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Game game = new Game();

    public BufferedImage getSpriteSheet(){
        return spriteSheet;
    }



}
```

The class that I'm calling (sprite) is:

```
package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class sprite{

    private double x;
    private double y;

    private BufferedImage sprite;

    public sprite(x, y, Game game){

        SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(game.getSpriteSheet());

        sprite = ss.grabImage(3, 3, 32, 32);
    }
```

BufferedImageLoader:

```
package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BufferedImageLoader {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) throws IOException{

        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
        return image;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ImageIO.read(new File("/astronaut_sprite1.png"));`  instead of `spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/astronaut_sprite1.png");`

Your folder structure:

```
-src
--com
---m14x
----game
-----BufferedImageLoader.java
-----Game.java
-----SpriteSheet.java
-res
---sprite_sheet.png
```

Your BufferedImageLoader class:

```
    public class BufferedImageLoader {
        private BufferedImage image;

        public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) throws IOException{
            System.out.println("PATH = " + path);
            File file = new File(path);

            if (file.exists()) {
                // First, make sure the path exists
System.out.println("File exists!");

            }
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                // This will tell you if it is a directory
 System.out.println("File is a directory!");

            }
            if (file.isFile()) {
                // Similarly, this will tell you if it's a file
System.out.println("File has a path!");

            }
            System.out.println("Trying to load image:");
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));

            //image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));

            System.out.println("Image path found. Returning...");
            return image;


        }

    }
```

Comment: check my update. well, you didn't provide the code for  your BufferedImageLoader class, but I know that ImageIO.read works properly

Comment: Sorry, I just posted the BufferedImageLoader class but within the class i already use ImageIO.read. My question is that even if I do use it, how do I use it to call the sprite I want from my spritesheet?

Comment: Since you're using getResourceAsStream(path) instead of specifying the absolute image path, you have to make sure that your resources folder is located in the right path, please check my updated answer once again.

Comment: Since I'm now using ImageIO.read should I replace the g.drawImage because it's now giving me an error asking if I want now create a class 'g'